# Is "set some time on the side" a common phrase?

Tags: expressions, idioms, time

I was convinced ***set some time on the side*** was a correct, fairly common expression. However, I am now in doubt because I can't find it via Google phrase match search. Is it idiomatic English?

For example, one might say in a meeting invite,

> I wanted to set some time on the side to discuss our Q2 plans.

Comment: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+some+time+aside%2Cset+some+time+on+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20some%20time%20aside%3B%2Cc0) would indicate that 'set some time on the side' is unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, *aside* was likely the intended word. *On the side* usually means something in addition to ones current activities, such as a side hustle, or a freelancing gig.